# Calculating summary scores using apply function and if else statement

Tags: r

I'm calculating two summary scores based on two 3-item scales. I'm calculating each like so:

```
tasksum <- paste("item",c(8,11,12), sep="")
all_data_2$summary_score_task <- apply(all_data_2[,tasksum], 1, sum, na.rm = FALSE)

activesum <- paste("item",c(14,21,25), sep="")
all_data_2$summary_score_act <- apply(all_data_2[,activesum], 1, sum, na.rm = FALSE)
```

I would like to accomplish the following:

1. for summary_score_task, in cases where "item8" is NA, I would like to calculate the summary score with the following expression: ((item11 + item12)/2)*3.  In cases where it's not NA, I would like to continue to calculate the summary score the same way as above.
2. for activity_score_act, in cases where "item21" is NA, I would like to calculate the summary score with the following expression: (2*ibr14 + ibr25). In cases where it's not NA, I would like to continue to calculate the summary score the same way as above.

I'm sort of new to R so I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, the function `rowSums` will handle the simple case of getting sums for every row (and more efficiently), though there is nothing wrong with using `apply`.

Second, to do the custom set of calculations you want to do, you can write your own anonymous function for use with apply that will do exactly the task you desire. `apply` with the margin argument set to 1 as you have will apply that function to each row of the input data. Without access to your data, here's an example:

```
set.seed(2)
all_data_2 <- data.frame(
  item8 = c(rnorm(48), NA, NA),
  item11 = rnorm(50),
  item12 = rnorm(50)
)

tasksum <- paste("item", c(8, 11, 12), sep = "")
  
all_data_2$summary_score_task <- 
  apply(all_data_2[,tasksum], 1, function(x) {
    # Note I am using the fact that I know the first element is item8
    if (is.na(x[1])) {
      ((x[2] + x[3])/2)*3
    } else {
      sum(x, na.rm = T)
    }
  })
```

You can accomplish your second task very similarly, I think. Examine your data after doing this and confirm it is doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry this is late, but thank you very much!